# how to pass dynamic URL in manifest.json in PWA

Tags: javascript, php, json, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I am using PWA to **add to home screen** task And I doing this in php. When I click **"Add to home screen button"** then script run. I made changes manifest.json according php as manifest.php. I am testing it on localhost by change https by ngrok.

I am trying to pass dynamic url in manifest file.

index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.php">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hey!!</h1>
<div class="add-to">
    <button class="add-to-btn">Add to home screen</button>
</div>

     
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   console.log("Will the service worker register?");
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
     .then(function(reg){
       console.log("Yes, it did.");
    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
   });
 }

 let deferredPrompt;
   var div = document.querySelector('.add-to');
   var button = document.querySelector('.add-to-btn');
   //div.style.display = 'none';

   window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
     // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
     e.preventDefault();
     // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
     deferredPrompt = e;
     div.style.display = 'block';

     button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
     //div.style.display = 'none';
     // Show the prompt
     deferredPrompt.prompt();
     // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
     deferredPrompt.userChoice
       .then((choiceResult) => {
         if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
           console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
         } else {
           console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
         }
         deferredPrompt = null;
       });
   });
   });
 </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

manifest.php is:

```
<?php
$starturl = 'https://621b16b2b7c5.ngrok.io/add_to_home_screen4/images/icon192.PNG';
$manifest =
[
"short_name"=> "BetaPage",
"name"=> "BetaPage",
"theme_color"=> "#4A90E2",
"background_color"=> "#F7F8F9",
"display"=> "standalone",
"icons"=> 
[
    [
        "src"=> "images/launcher-icon-1x.png",
        "type"=> "image/png",
        "sizes"=> "48x48"
    ],
    [
        "src"=> "images/launcher-icon-2x.png",
        "type"=> "image/png",
        "sizes"=> "96x96"
    ],
    [
        "src"=> "images/chat1.png",
        "type"=> "image/png",
        "sizes"=> "144x144"
    ],
    [
        "src"=> "images/icon192.png",
        "type"=> "image/png",
        "sizes"=> "192x192"
    ]
],
"start_url"=> $starturl
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($manifest);
```

When I reload the webpage then below error occur:
[image]

I have to press ctrl+F5 each time to run the code. Why?

Comment: Are you sure ngrock is working and serving your content?

Comment: yes...When I press ctrl+F5 then works perfect

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution. MY service-worker.js file was not correct. Now I paste below code in service-worker.js and it wored.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
```

Comment: Now got another problem

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205107/do-not-close-browser-after-install-pwa